# Best Practices in Big Data?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hadoop, twitter, bigdata, twitter4j

From your experience I have the following system for big data:

Our main goal is to analyse billions of daily tweets and show them in our portal for the decisions maker. The types of graph included bar chart, column chart, network graph.
So far our system like this:

1. Cloudera platform (CDH) for only storing the data in HDFS
2. Apache Flume for streaming tweets from GNIP
3. Elastic search and php to develope the charts

I want to know what is the best combination of product that can produce the online visualization and the offline one on the big data?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can continue to work with **Hadoop** for offline processing of big data
2. You can move **Apache Storm** Or **Apache Spark** for real time processing of big data.
   Spark+ HBase combination works well for rela time processing of data. Spark in-memory database coupled with HBase makes real time querying of Big data very quicker.   Have a  look at this [article](http://zohararad.github.io/presentations/big-data-introduction/)

Key takeaways:

[Various Hadoop tools for Batch processing](http://zohararad.github.io/presentations/big-data-introduction/?full#23)  and 
[Real time data processing](http://zohararad.github.io/presentations/big-data-introduction/?full#36)

Comment: Why do you prefer Storm among flume or kafka

Comment: This one may answer your queries  : http://hortonworks.com/blog/discover-hdp-2-2-apache-kafka-apache-storm-stream-data-processing/